# Java Tip Calculator for newbie

Tags: java

I hope I'm posting in the right place.

I'm pretty new to Java (meaning this is only my third program besides 'hello world').

I have a tip calculator I'm working on for an assignment. I'm not getting an 'error' as such,
but the method for splitting the bill always seems to think each customer pays 'infinity'.
I have my program set up in two classes: tipCalc1 and tipCalc2 (no points for originality of course).
The program appears to run without issue besides the 'infinity' issue.

Here's what I have so far. Any assistance appreciated, thanks.

```
***TipCalc1 Class:***

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tipcalc1
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Tip Calculator! ");
        TipCalc2 Calculator = new TipCalc2();
        System.out.println("Please enter the bill amount: ");
        TipCalc2.calBill();
        System.out.println("What percentage would you like to tip?: ");
        Calculator.percTip();

    }

}


***And the tipCalc2 class which does the dirty work:***

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TipCalc2
{
    static double bill;
    double tip;
    double total;
    double split;
    double splitPrompt;
    double Y;
    double N;
    double billPerPerson;

        static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void calBill()
        {
             bill = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        public void percTip()
        {
             tip = scan.nextDouble();
            if(tip<1)
            {
                total = bill * tip;
            }
        else total = bill * (tip/100);
        System.out.println("Your total is: " + total);
        Split();
        }


        public void Split()
        {
        System.out.println("Would you like to split the bill? ");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for YES or 0 for NO: ");

        splitPrompt = scan.nextDouble();
        if(splitPrompt == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Your total is: " + total);
            System.out.println("Thankyou. Goodbye.");
            System.out.println("End Program");  
        }
        if(splitPrompt == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("How many ways would you like to split the bill? ");
            splitPrompt = scan.nextDouble();
            billPerPerson = total / split;
            System.out.println("Each person pays: " + billPerPerson);
            System.out.println("Thankyou. Goodbye.");
            System.out.println("End Program.");  

        }
        else System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? What are expected outputs? What are you getting instead?

Comment: While you are still a beginner, now is the best time to get out of the habit of using `double` to store an amount of money.  If you use `double` in this way, you will introduce errors as soon as you start doing arithmetic.  I strongly recommend _either_ using `BigDecimal` to store your money, _or_ using `int` to store a number of cents.

Answer (score 3):

The default value for `split` (because you have not initialized it with another value) is `0.0`, therefore, when you do

```
billPerPerson = total / split;
```

you divide by `0.0`, so you will get `Infinity`.

**Notes:**

- Since your variable `splitPrompt` is double and computers doesn't store real values with a 100% accuracy, you *shouldn't* compare it with `0.0`. Since this variable will store `0` or `1` for input, you can declare it as `int`, which will be accurate.
- Try to follow Java naming conventions. Use `mixedCase` for methods/variables and use `CamelCase` for classes/interfaces.
- In the method `split()`, you should use an `if-else if-else` structure:

  ```
  if(splitPrompt == 0) {
  ...
  }
  else if(splitPrompt == 1) {
  ...
  }
  else {
  ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake.

Change

```
System.out.println("How many ways would you like to split the bill?
splitPrompt = scan.nextDouble();
```

to

```
System.out.println("How many ways would you like to split the bill?
split = scan.nextDouble();
```

since you never change split which, like all double variables, is initialized to 0.0.

Also, you should use ints where appropriate as not all of the numbers should be doubles. Or even better, use 'y' and 'n' chars.

Comment: Yep, my apologies for jumping to conclusions a bit early

Answer (score 0):

**Class TipCalc2**

```
//Total = **bill** * (gets percentage in decimal 15 = 0.15) + **bill**
```

Line 18 needs to be:

```
total = bill * (tip / 100) + bill;
```

Line 36/37 needs to be:

```
split = splitPrompt = scan.nextInt();
billPerPerson = total / split;

//You're dividing billPerPerson = total by ZERO (split);
```

Line 36/37 original:

```
billPerPerson = total / split;
```